# javascript each - autodetect name of val in (key,val)

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a JSON file that has more name value pairs than I care to type in.  Either lazy or elegant.  Instead of using what I have below where I have to type in all the name values pairs there must be a property of val like val.name so not to have to type all the other pairs out.  What's the proper terminology to search find the answer?  or the code would be nice too :)

This is what I started using when I thought, "crap, I have to type all that *#&@$ out!"

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
            items.push(key + val.TimeStamp + val.bandwidth + );
```

JSON

```
{
    "Router": "HS-DSCS1",
    "router_data": [
        {
            "TimeStamp": "2012/01/01 06:00:00",
            "NeighborIP": "192.168.1.1",
            "State": "Full",
            "Bytes001": "21362.95663",
            "Bytes002": "2.67 KB",
            "Bytes003": "9887.99707",
            "Bytes004": "1.24 KB",
            "Bytes005": "Serial0/1/0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What's your question? The iteration over data or the one over val?

Comment: Huh? Your code sample is _already_ iterating over the `data` object, so why can't you do the same thing for `val`?

Comment: I want to push all the properties of the object into the object without haveing to type val.TimeStamp, val.BandWidth, etc.  seems like that is the long way of populating an object from a JSON array (data)

Comment: @nnnnnn makes sense, so I can use and each statement with in the items.push()?

Comment: Perhaps you should start with valid JSON?

Comment: Yeup, I noticed that.  It's fixed in the question.  But I think I need to go back and explore my JSON structure and start again.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're just doing string concatenation. If so ...

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push(key + $.map(val, String).join('') );
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/ZVDcy/

---

Or if you're building a new Array, you could do this...

```
var items = $.map(data, function(val, key) {
    return key + $.map(val, String).join('');
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/ZVDcy/1/

Comment: I tried to verify that all the columns from the json by using alert(items.join('\n'));  but only see the first set of values.  Is there a better way to print out the contents of an array to the console to verify whats going in?

Comment: The browser's console should show you exactly what you're getting. Is `data` more deeply nested than just one level? Can you show your data structure in your question?

Comment: @rd42: Your JSON isn't a valid structure. The `[ ]` is out of place, and appears as though they should just be removed. Also, I'm not certain what your output should look like. It would seem a little odd to concatenate all the values into a single string.

Comment: Yes I just noticed that.  I think maybe I'm asking the question wrong, or I'm setting up my JSON wrong or both.  Maybe I asked my question to early.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question right, just use a `for..in`.

```
for (field in val){
   // something with val[field]
}
```